# Need to use a variable in an os.system command in python

Tags: python, os.system

I am new to python and I need to use a variable in the `os.system` command, here's my code so far

```
import os , sys
s = raw_input('test>')
```

then i want to use the varable `s` in an `os.system` command so I was thinking something like `os.system("shutdown -s -t 10 -c" 's')`

I don't want answers for that specific command I just want to know in general but if you are going to use an example use shutdown

Answer (score 4):

> then i want to use the varable s in an os.system

Use [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function.

```
os.system("shutdown -s -t 10 -c {}".format(s))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.system` to execute the particular command, in which case you can join the two strings either by using the `+` operator, string formatting (`.format()`), string substitution or some other method.

However, consider the case when the user enters the command `5; rm -rf /` or some other [malicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection) command.  Instead of using `os.system` you might want to take a look at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

If you use subprocess you might find the following example handy:

```
import subprocess
s = raw_input('test>')
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-s", "-t", "10", "-c", s])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), pass a list of args and you can add the variable wherever you like:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["shutdown", some_var ,"-s", "-t" "10", "-c"])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) takes a *string* as the argument, so you can use anything that modifies a string. For example, [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
os.system('shutdown -s -t 10 -c {0}'.format(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing place-holder **"%s string alongside os.system"** should work.

os.system() will execute the command in shell.

```
import os
var = raw_input('test>') # changed "s" variable to "var" to keep clean
os.system("shutdown -%s -t 10 -c", %(var)) # "var" will be passed to %s place holder
```

Answer (score -1):

```
os.system("shutdown -s -t 10 -c" + s)
```

1. The plus sign joins two strings
2. No quotes are used around `s`.  That way you get the value the user entered and not just a literal "s".